# Remove subdocument structure from document but keep content?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How would I take a document structure like this:

```
{"latitude" : 32.7874, "longitude" : -96.7989, "machine" : {"ip" : "1.1.1.1", load : 1 }}
```

with a document as one of the fields and expand the machine document into the main document:

```
{"latitude" : 32.7874, "longitude" : -96.7989, "ip" : "1.1.1.1", load : 1 }
```

Comment: As a note, this is a bare bones example of my data that resulted from using `$lookup` and `as:"machine"`.  If there is a way to directly insert it into the document without this intermediate step, that would also work for me.

Comment: You can add `$project` stage to aggregation pipeline as mentioned in my post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple aggregation query, try

```
db.doc.aggregate([
    {$project:{latitude:1, longitude:1, ip:"$machine.ip", load:"$machine.load"}}
])
```

From your sample document, it will transform into

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56eb51b0a968afd923923dcd"), 
    "latitude" : 32.7874, 
    "longitude" : -96.7989, 
    "ip" : "1.1.1.1", 
    "load" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I know about `$project`, but I was unaware I could do `"$machine.ip"`.

Comment: Best possible way to know is to give it a try.